# Cesium polylines on webserver

Tags: cesiumjs

I've a problem I don't know how to solve. I've downloaded Cesium-1.29 and made a small program to display a track (polyline) in a mountain area. Locally on the development system the track shows up. When I move everything to a webserver the mountain area shows up, but not the track.
What is the problem?
Have a look at: home.kpn.nl/udo00026/Cesium_3D_World.html
I'm pretty I miss some understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
try...

polyline : {
    followSurface : false,
}
```

Something I noticed...

your map.entities._entities.length is 1, and if you look at it...

map.entities._entities._array[0] you'll see it's the polyline you're adding. So it's there, just not "visible" for some reason. I have also added other polylines to your project just using the console and they are not showing up.

It *has* to be something to do with how you are configuring your viewer, at least that's my bet. Trying playing around with this [online cesium playground](https://analyticalgraphicsinc.github.io/cesium-google-earth-examples/examples/polyline.html) regarding polylines.

Hope that at least adds some insight.